# Image Map tooltip having hyperlink not working in Internet Explorer Version 11

Tags: javascript, html, css, imagemap

Have to create an image map such that if I hover over the elements it should show a tool-tip text. This tool-tip text has a hyperlink. This works in other browsers but not working in IE 11. I am new to image mapping, html, css, JavaScript.

Have tried using 'div' tag instead of 'p' tag; adding width and height to the image. Nothing works.

//css

```
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0 1px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext .exampletext {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

//body - image map

```
    <div id="image_map">
      <map name="map_example">
         <div class="tooltip">
            <area shape="rect" coords="40,40,400,400">
```

//spanning to include tooltip text with hyperlink

```
                <span class="tooltiptext" style="top:50px;left:240px">
                     <p class=exampletext>Id:  -129<br>
link:  <a href='https://www.google.com/' target="_blank">GoogleLink</a>
</p>
                    </span>
             </div>
       </map>
    </div>
```

//image over which mappng is done

```
    <div id="image">
        <img src="https://assets.materialup.com/uploads/82eae29e-33b7-4ff7-be10-df432402b2b6/preview" alt="image map example" width="auto"
            height="auto" usemap="#map_example">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Should work in IE as well.

Comment: Are you sure that DIVs inside img MAP are valid HTML? Check the permitted parents of the AREA tag here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area, DIV is not on the list of phrasing-content. What are you trying to achieve? image maps are somewhat old (non responsive!!). And also, your AREA tag is not closed. Check your html using some HTML validation website first.

Comment: needed to add tooltip to the image map hovering with tooltip text containing hyperlink. Has it been without hyperlink, I would have used "title". I couldn't find any other option. Please suggest other options if there are any.

Comment: The AREA tag already supports an `href` attribute like an A tag. You can use `href` as if it was an A tag and `title` for the tooltip.

Comment: If you still need to style the tooltip, you can use absolute positioned elements wrapped with the image all inside the same container or create an SVG if you need shapes other than rectangles.